# Create two rows of turtles with an equal x-cor distance

Tags: netlogo

first of all, sorry for my english. I hope you can understand me.

I'm trying to create an ABM of couple bargaining. In order to accomplish this, I want to set two rows of men and women, like in the "Party" Netlogo model. 
As I see, I want to have one row with men disposed with equal distances between every man, like man, (5 empty patches), man (5 positions), man... starting with one on the left in a determined position. And the same goes for woman's row.

How can I do this?

With this:

```
setxy random-xcor 15 ; for the man's row
setxy random-xcor 15 ; for the woman's row
```

I can get two rows of men and women within a fixed axis, and a random-xcor on the other axis, but i don't get equal distances between turtles.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
create-turtles num-men [ setxy who * distance 15]
create-turtles num-women [setxy (who - num-men) * distance -15]
```

For example,

if you have 5 turtles, their whos will be [0 1 2 3 4] and a distance of 5, thus their xcors will be [0 5 10 15 20] respectively. The only reason this would work is if the men's whos start at 0. You may need to offset their whos by how many other turtles were created before...see the women.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it worked for my purposes!

Comment: @MikeNZT  stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

```
  ask patches with [pxcor mod 5 = 0 and abs pycor = 1] [
    sprout 1 [
      set shape "person" 
      set color ifelse-value (pycor > 0) [blue][pink]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: While the code provided might solve the problem from the OP, it would be helpful to explain what is going on and why this code is answering the original questions. Other users might benefit from sich background information with similar questions.